# element detection inside when I click the element

Tags: javascript, events, onclick

I have defined a click function in the container element. and the element inside this container element is the same size as the container. but when I implement the click event  it detects   not the container. it detects the container in inside element

```
<div onclick='toggle_class()'>
  <img src='source_img'/>
</div>

<script>
 function toggle_class(){
   event.target.classList.add('open');
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
` function toggle_class(){
   event.target.classList.add('open');
 }`
```

With

```
 function toggle_class(){
   event.currentTarget.classList.add('open');
 }
```

Comment: What is `event` and from where it comes ?

Comment: @Lalit Yeah. That's what I was trying to do.

Comment: @user2486 We can pass it explicitly from where we are calling the function and in some browsers we don't have to do that.